# Connecting balanced output with unbalaned input using adaptor

Tags: audio, output, input

I want to connect my audio interface (balanced TRS jack output) with guitar pedal (unbalanced TS jack input) and I wonder if this kind of adapter will work:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B001JYSMV0/ref=psdc_172544_t1_B000068O4M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001JYSMV0)

I'd plug TRS male to my output in interface and then connect TS cable to female input of this adapter, then the other end of TS cable would go to the guitar pedal.
Can that adaptor I linked above be used interchangeably with the one below?
[https://www.amazon.com/Hosa-GPP-290-TRS-TS-Adaptor/dp/B000068O4M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000068O4M)

The first one (female TS to male TRS) I'd plug on the output side of my audio interface and then go to guitar pedal with TS cable.

The second one (female TRS to male TS) I'd plug on the input side of my guitar pedal and use TRS cable to connect it to audio interface.

So are they interchangeable and will either of them work for sending signal from my audio interface to guitar pedal?

Comment: What do the data sheets tell you?

Comment: Manuals didn't tell me anything about it, unfortunately.